# find actual email id of Exchange DL List

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server, webdav, exchange-server-2003

I have been developing code to send emails using Exchange 2003 Distrbution List, but unfortunately i could not able to find the exact email id of DL List, i think if we can able to find email id of DL list then we can easily send email to entire DL.

So can anybody know how to find exact email id of Exchagne 2003 DL list, please help me out..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to find DL email id ie..

```
DirectorySearcher src = new DirectorySearcher("(anr=" + TestDL + ")");
foreach (SearchResult res in src.FindAll())
 {
 emailAddress = emailAddress + res.Properties["mail"][0].ToString() + ";" ;
 }
```

"FindAll" is used to find the email id similar to TestDL variable email and also it is used to find DL Email id.

For example output would be textdl@testserver.com